# Swift - Correct way to create Custom Controls

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Actually, I have a UINavigationBar that is the same in entire application. To not make the same UINavigationBar in each view with Xcode and storyboard, I thought to make my own UINavigationBar and implement it in the AppDelegate class.

The first thing that I did in the application function was the next:

```
mainWindow = storyBoard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainCtrl") as! ViewController
let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(pEvenColor)
navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(pEvenColor)
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.sizeToFit()
navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
mainWindow!.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

This works fine. The UINavigationbar shows perfect in the Main View.

I thought late that maybe will be possible to reduce the code and do something like a *function that return* a **UINavigationBar** and use this directly:

`mainWindow!.view.addSubview(someClass())`

So, I add a new Cocoa Touch Class named **NavigationAppBar**, that inherits from UINavigationBar and set all same code in the **drawRect()** function, but this doesn't work.

Then in the AppDelegate:

```
var myNavBar = NavigationAppBar()
mainWindow!.view.addSubview(myNavBar)
```

**This doesn't work. Evidently, the drawRect() method never calls, but I don't know the correct way to do something like this. I'm doing something wrong, but, with this scenario, what is the correct way to make my own UINavigationBar (in a class or something) and add it to any view?**

Regards and sorry for paste all code here.

Comment: Don't add the navigation bar direction to the view. Use a `UINavigationController` and initialize it with the method `-initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:`. You could also create a subclass of `UINavigationController` that will always set the navigation bar class for you. If you don't use a navigation controller, you lose out on a bunch of functionality that makes pushing/popping the navigation stack.

Comment: You refer that the mainView sould be a NavigationController or that I sould implement all this in a NavigationController class?

Comment: 1. I would create a `UINavigationBar` subclass that will customize its own appearance. This way that logic is self-contained.
2. I would use a `UINavigationController` that is initialized with that customer `UINavigationBar` subclass.
3. I would consider also subclassing the `UINavigationController` so you both know to always use that navigation controller and know that the navigation bar will always be correct.

Comment: Ok, I understand right now. Thanks for your aclaration @AdamPro13